# "double" does not print decimals

Tags: c++

i was wondering why in this program, "pi_estimated" wouldn't print out as a number with decimal places although the variable was declared as a "double". However, it prints out an integer.

```
double get_pi(double required_accuracy)
{
    double pi_estimation=0.0;
    int x,y;
    double p=0.0,q=0.0,r=0.0;
    int D=0;
    for(int N=1;N<=1e2;N++)
    {
        x = rand()%100;
        p = (x/50.0 - 1.0)/100.0;
        y = rand()%100;
        q = (y/50.0 - 1.0)/100.0;
        r = p*p + q*q;
        if((sqrt(r))<1.0)
        {
            D++;
           pi_estimation = 4.0*(double (D/N));
        }
        if(double (4/(N+1)) < (required_accuracy*pi_estimation/100.0))
        {
            cout<<pi_estimation<<endl;
            return (pi_estimation);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double pi_approx=0.0, a, actual_accuracy=0.0;
    for(a=0.1;a>=1e-14;a/=10)
    {
        pi_approx = get_pi(a);
        actual_accuracy = (fabs((pi_approx - M_PI)/(M_PI)))*100.0;
        cout<<actual_accuracy<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `double(D/N)` isn't what you think. Print it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
pi_estimation = 4.0*(double (D/N));
```

Since `D` and `N` are both `int`s, `D/N` is an `int`. Casting the `int` to a `double` cannot magically make decimals appear out of nowhere.

Here's the line, fixed:

```
pi_estimation = 4.0 * (((double) D) / N));
```

You could also multiply first, so you don't need so many parens:

```
pi_estimation = 4.0 * D / N;
```

`D` is being multiplied by `4.0`, so it becomes a `double` because `double * int = double`. Then it's divided by `N`. Since `(x * y) / z` === `x * (y / z)` (associative property), the expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
pi_estimation = 4.0*(double (D/N));
```

`D` and `N` are both integers, so `D/N` is an integer that you are casting to a double and then multiplying by `4.0`.

You want to do this:

```
pi_estimation = 4.0 * (static_cast<double>(D) / N));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since D and N are both integral types, D/N is performed in integer arithmetic; the cast to double happens too late as precision is lost prior to the cast.

One fix is to write `4.0 * D / N`. This will ensure that everything is calculated in floating point. (Since `*` and `/` have the same precedence, you don't need to write `(double)`.)